# Check if archives are identical

Tags: java

I'm using a shell script to automatically create a zipped backup of various directories every hour. If I haven't been working on any of them for quite some time, this creates alot of duplicate archives. MD5 hashes of the files don't match, because they do have different filenames & creation dates etc.

Other than making sure there won't be duplicates in the first place, another option is checking if filesizes match, but that doesn't necesseraly mean they are duplicates.

Filenames are done like so;

```
Qt_2012-03-15_23_00.tgz
Qt_2012-03-16_00_00.tgz
```

So maybe it would be an option to check if files have identical filesizes **consequently** (if that's the right word for it.)

**Pseudo code:**

```
int previoussize = 0;
String previouspath = null;
String Filename = null;
String workDir = "/path/to/workDir ";
String processedDir = "/path/to/processedDir ";

//Loop over all files
for file in workDir
{
    //Match
    if(file.size() == previoussize)
    {
        if(previouspath!=null) //skip first loop
        {
            rm previouspath; //Delete file
        }
    }
    else //No Match
    {
      /*If there's no match, we can move the previous file 
        to another directory so it doesn't get checked again*/
        if(previouspath!=null) //skip first loop
        {
            mv previouspath processedDir/Filename;
        }
    }
    previoussize = file.size();
    previouspath = file.path();
    Filename = file.name();
}
```

Example:

```
Qt_2012-03-15_23_00.tgz 10KB
Qt_2012-03-16_00_00.tgz 10KB
Qt_2012-03-16_01_00.tgz 10KB
Qt_2012-03-16_02_00.tgz 15KB
Qt_2012-03-16_03_00.tgz 10KB
Qt_2012-03-16_04_00.tgz 10KB
```

If I'm correct this would only delete the first 2 and the second to last one. The third and the fourth should be moved to the processedDir.

So I guess I have 2 questions:

1. Would my pseudo code work the way I intend it to? (I find these things rather confusing.)
2. Is there a better/simpler/faster way? Because even though the chance of accidentally deleting non-identicals like that is very small, it's still a chance.

Comment: Have you tried *cmp(1)*?

Comment: if (archive1.equals(archive2))

Comment: i didn't get your question :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of alternatives:

- Deploy a version control system such as Git, Subversion, etc, and write a script that periodically checks in any changes.  This will save a lot of space because only files that have actually changed get saved, and because changes to text files will be stored as diffs.
- Use an incremental backup tool.  [This article](http://www.junauza.com/2009/01/7-best-freeopen-source-backup-software.html) lists a number of alternatives.

Normal practice is to put the version control system / backups on a different machine, but you don't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear if this need to run as a batch. If it's manual, you can run BeyondCompare or any decent comparison tool to diff the two archives

Comment: The program would need to constantly run in the background. Checking the workDir every hour.